# Guardar XML en asp Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, asp

tengo problemas con un Javascript para guardar un XML que proviene de un textarea :

```
function descargarArchivo(nombreArchivo) {
var texto = document.getElementById('txtArea').value;
var contenidoEnBlob = new Blob([texto], {type: 'text/xml'});
var lector = new FileReader();

lector.onload = function(event) {

var guardar = document.createElement('a');
guardar.href = event.target.result;
guardar.target = '_blank';
guardar.download = nombreArchivo || 'archivo.dat';
var clicEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
'view': window,
'bubbles': false,
'cancelable': true
});

guardar.dispatchEvent(clicEvent);
};

lector.readAsDataURL(contenidoEnBlob);
};

window.onload = function() {

document.getElementById('boton').addEventListener( 'click', function () {

descargarArchivo('archivo.XML');

}, false);
}
```

[image: este es el textarea]
[image: como queda]

Comment: Buenas Luis, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento basico del sitio. Dices que tienes problemas,... puedes explicar mejor eso?¿ te da fallos por consola? qué navegador usas? ( no todos aceptan `blob`). Para más informacion, lee [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Hola  lois6b, es con la consola ASP, y no me marca ningún error, solo que al abrir el el archivo XML que se ha generado no se ve ningún dato del XML

Comment: El XML ya estpa en el textarea o lo estas cargando desde otro archivo ? si ya esta cargado no necesitas el FileReader

Comment: estoy cargando el código de una consulta de SQL que se deposita en textarea, ya no tengo que generar los nodos, solo necesito que se guarde correctamente se debe de mostrar asi: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-I5E6etolNeM/WZrptFO7EXI/AAAAAAAAKrc/X5n5oycMVdEfXXXYW0rIkxKK8HBZ3Ku8gCLcBGAs/s1600/xml-2.png